# What does $R^{(E)} = \mathbb{Q}$ mean?

Tags: ring-theory, notation, modules

[Context](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2765727/show-mathbbq-is-not-a-projective-mathbbz-module)

> Okay, I think I understand- using the section you have linked to as a
>   guide, letting $E$ be the generating set for $\mathbb{Q}$ and $R^{(E)}$
>   $= \mathbb{Q}$, in particular we can use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module over itself, so let $M = \mathbb{Z}$ and then
>   given an arbitrary map $\phi : E \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, there exists
>   a unique homomorphism $\psi : \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such
>   that $\phi = \psi \circ i$, where $i : E \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is
>   the inclusion map. However, we have just shown that the only $\psi$
>   that exists is $0$, and $0 \circ i = 0 \neq \phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, $R^{E}=\mathbb Q$ is the statement that if $\mathbb Q$ were a free $\mathbb Z$-module with basis $E$, then this structure would define an isomorphism $\oplus_{E} \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Q$, where here we think about $\mathbb Z$ as being the ring $R$.